# Custom gauge fails to draw at runtime

Tags: delphi, components

`FPercentDone` was `0`, was assigning it's value in the wrong place. Adding `UpdatePercent` procedure and calling it when a value changes fixes it and everything gets drawn.

Dumb mistake, sorry for wasting your time.

---

First of all, this is my first attempt at writing a component of any kind. Properties, methods etc. were an easy part, however I have hit a wall with drawing to the canvas. I am sure this is some rookie mistake, but I simply don't see it. I have stared at the `TGauge` included with delphi because I am trying something similar but simpler, it is still just a horizontal bar. I am failing at making it draw the progress at run time, that is the weirdest part, for me anyway, that I can see it *working* at design time but not when I run it... I do get the background coloring right at least, but no progress bar.

Without any code pasting, since it is similar to `TGauge` anyway. I have two `TBitmap's`, one for background the other for the progress bar itself, I fill one with background color, draw that to the component canvas, if there are borders offset the origin of the second one and decrease its rectangle, paint it with the progress color and draw that to the canvas... It seemed this simple to me, but what am I doing wrong?

Relevant code:

```
type
  TCustomGaugeComp = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FMaxValue, FMinValue, FCurValue: DWord;
    FFillBackColor, FFillForeColor: TColor;
    FPercentDone: Real;
    FBorderStyle: TBorderStyle;
    FBorderWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetMaxValue(Value: DWord);
    procedure SetMinValue(Value: DWord);
    procedure SetProgress(Value: DWord);
    procedure SetFillBackColor(Value: TColor);
    procedure SetFillForeColor(Value: TColor);
    procedure SetBorderStyle(Value: TBorderStyle);
    function GetPercentDone: String;
    procedure SetBorderWidth(Value: integer);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Align;
    property BorderStyle: TBorderStyle read FBorderStyle write SetBorderStyle default bsSingle;
    property BorderWidth: Integer read FBorderWidth write SetBorderWidth default 1;
    property Constraints;
    property Enabled;
    property Font;
    property FillForeColor: TColor read FFillForeColor write SetFillForeColor default clBlack;
    property FillBackColor: TColor read FFillBackColor write SetFillBackColor default clWhite;
    property MinValue: DWord read FMinValue write SetMinValue default 0;
    property MaxValue: DWord read FMaxValue write SetMaxValue default 100;
    property Progress: DWord read FCurValue write SetProgress default 0;
    property PercentDone: String read GetPercentDone;
    property Visible;
  end;


procedure TCustomGaugeComp.Paint;
var
  Background, Progress: TBitMap;
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Background := TBitMap.Create;
    try
      Background.Height := Height;
      Background.Width := Width;
      Background.Canvas.Brush.Color := FFillBackColor;
      Background.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      Background.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
      Progress := TBitMap.Create;
      try
        Progress.Height := Height;
        Progress.Width := Width;
        if FBorderStyle = bsSingle then
        begin
          Progress.Height := Progress.Height - BorderWidth*2;
          Progress.Width := Progress.Width - BorderWidth*2;
        end;
        Progress.Width := trunc(Progress.Width*FPercentDone/100);
        Progress.Canvas.Brush.Color := FFillForeColor;
        Progress.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Progress.Width,Progress.Height));
        Background.Canvas.Draw(BorderWidth,BorderWidth,Progress);
      finally
        Progress.Free;
      end;
      Draw(0,0,Background);
    finally
      Background.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**RePaint** (or Refresh) is called whenever a value changes: min/max/position/borderwidth.

In fact it is not acting perfectly at design time either, progress is drawn, at times, sometimes not drawn at all until I just *OPEN* the Object Inspector, just go with my mouse there... `TGauge` uses `CopyMode` excessively, I just started this and I do not really understand `CopyMode` values yet or its proper use, so copy-pasting and tweaking the code just will not do.

Comment: I don't know a thing about Delphi, but I can say this: You are much more likely to get useful responses if you show us the most relevant bits of your code. If it's very similar to something that comes with Delphi and that's known to work, you might find the following strategy useful: start with `TGauge` itself, gradually modify it to bring it nearer to your code, and see where it breaks. Or state with your code and gradually `TGauge`ify it and see where it starts working. Or pick a point halfway in between, see whether it works, and keep subdividing.

Comment: We really need the code to answer your question. Did you override the paint method?

Comment: To elaborate on NGLN's comment, the declaration should look like `procedure Paint; override;` You don't necessarily have to call Paint yourself, let Windows call it for you. Instead, call `Invalidate;` and that will tell Windows to call Paint when it gets a chance.

Comment: @NGLN yes, paint is overridden. Code added.

Comment: @JerryDodge, what is the difference between invalidate or repain/refresh? and where should i actually call invalidate? This is probably what i am missing...

Comment: Just something to point out: for better performance, don't create/free your bitmaps inside the paint method. This method can be called hundreds of times in 1 second. Create them in the main class. When properties change, draw to this smaller bitmap but not the control canvas. Then call Invalidate to tell Windows that it needs to be repainted. Windows will call Paint when it feels it's necessary. In the Paint procedure, simply merge the bitmaps together onto the canvas.

Comment: `Invalidate` signals Windows to ask the control to redraw itself at Windows earliest convenience, likely somewhere in the near future. `Repaint` calls `Invalidate` _and_ requests the parent redrawn immediately. `Refresh` just calls `Repaint`. Invalidate is better, because subsequent calls will be combined which reduces flickering and CPU load.

Comment: This `Paint` code is just fine (read: does what it should do). Can we see the declaration of your class?

Comment: @NGLN, declaration added. I'll fix the Paint and make it proper, however i dont want to continue until i understand what i'm doing wrong here. Please advise, replaced all refreshes with invalidate, at design time it's better now, when i open a saved project with this gauge on it, it still does get drawn thought until i select it at design time, obviously still no draw at runtime

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, only the background bitmap is drawn (it seems), meaning that if i change the background bitmap color, what i get drawn is just the whole client area of the component filled with that color, that's it, no progress bar which should already be in the background bitmap, this is the weird part... It (the progress bar) gets drawn at design time, but not runtime. I will add the breakpoint and see just to be safe

Comment: @Raith - Put a breakpoint on `Progress.Width := trunc(..` line and hover over 'FPercentDone'. If it's '0', it is expected that you don't see the progress bar.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, you were correct, it was in fact 0 all the time. Then why did it work at design time? I was setting FPercentDone in my sting PercentDone, which i wanted to be read-only. Everything works if i add "UpdatePercent" procedure and call it if any value changes, however I dont know if that's the best way to solve this? Any quick tips on what would be the best way to implement that?

Comment: @Raith - From here, the way I see it, your mistake was to bypass the getter. I.e. if you had assigned the width `trunc(Progress.Width*PercentDone/100);` it would work correctly (notice 'PercentDone' as opposed to 'FPercentDone'), assuming the getter was calculating the percentage from FCurValue, FMinValue and FMaxValue. As to why it had been working at design time, I really can't guess with what we have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FPercentDone` was `0`, was assigning it's value in the wrong place. Adding `UpdatePercent` procedure and calling it when a value changes fixes it and everything gets drawn.

Dumb mistake, sorry for wasting your time.